# Errors using Find Method and Match Function in Excel VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro to create a large number of scatter plots for a large quantity of data. The data set for each chart is on its own tab. The independent variable is always in column J, but the location of the dependent variable can change. I put the name of the dependent variable in cell K1 to tell the macro which column is the dependent variable for this chart. I need to program logic that looks for the name of the variable in the header row so that I can set the range for `Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values`.

Here's what my data sets look like (I can't show the real thing due to proprietary information):

[image: Sample Data Table]

I tried the find method, but it returned an error that indicates it can't find what it's looking for:

```
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set oChart = ws.ChartObjects.Add (Left:=0, Width:=375, Top:=0, Height:=225)
    Set rXVal = ws.Range("J3")
    Set rXVal = Range(rXVal, rXVal.End(xlDown))
    sLookup = ws.Range("K1").Value
    Set rHeader = Range(ws.Range("J2"), ws.Range("J2").End(xlToRight))
    Set rCell = rHeader.Find(What:=sLookup, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, After:=Cells(1, 1), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
    Set rYVal = Range(rCell.Offset(1, 0), rCell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))
    With oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rXVal
        .Values = rYVal
    End With
Next
```

Then I tried Match, but I still get an error indicating that it can't find the lookup value:

```
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set oChart = ws.ChartObjects.Add (Left:=0, Width:=375, Top:=0, Height:=225)
    Set rXVal = ws.Range("J3")
    Set rXVal = Range(rXVal, rXVal.End(xlDown))
    sLookup = ws.Range("K1").Value
    Set rHeader = Range(ws.Range("A2"), ws.Range("A2").End(xlToRight))
    iCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sLookup, rHeader, 0)
    Set rYVal = ws.Cells(3, iCol)
    Set rYVal = Range(rYVal, rYVal.End(xlDown))
    With oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .XValues = rXVal
        .Values = rYVal
    End With
Next
```

I tried changing `sLookup` to `CLng(sLookup)` and omitting the `WorksheetFunction` piece, but I still get errors that indicate it can't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Quick note - you almost do it everywhere, but make sure you always add the worksheet before the range, i.e. `set rHeader = ws.Range(ws.Range("A2"), ...`, same for `rYVal`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're main problem is the assignment to `rHeader` is wrong. Try

`Set rHeader = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 10), ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))`

Then, in the first variant, get rid of the `After:=Cells(1, 1)`

Last, check if the Find-Command returned anything by checking it's result:

```
if rCell is nothing then
    Debug.print "Not found..." 
else
  ...
end if
```